# Grouping categorical variable in dynamic dataframe in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have categorical variables based on states.

I want to create a `dynamic dataframe` with same name and data of filtered state only.

Like for `DataAL`, we will have all data of **AL states only**.

**Code 1:**

```
l = []

for i in a:
    print(i)
    l[i] = df4[df4["Provider State"].str.contains(i)]
    l[i] = pd.DataFrame(l[i])
    l[i].head()
```

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

---

**Code 2:**

```
l = []

for i in range(len(a)):
    print(i)
    l[i] = df4[df4["Provider State"].str.contains(a[i])]
    l[i] = pd.DataFrame(l[i])
    l[i].head()
```

> IndexError: list assignment index out of range